# Where do I drill my homebrew fermenting fridge?

Tags: beer, equipment, refrigerator

I just bought a freezer for use as a fermenting unit. How do I know where to drill my holes? Any advice greatly appreciated. I cannot see any specific advice on the net.

Comment: What holes do you want to drill and why? I don't think you need any; you'd only ruin the insulation. The thermostat probe just fits in when you close the lid / door on it.

Comment: I am wondering the same. Not talking about a FREEZER, but a FRIDGE. I am wondering if I can drill a hole in the side, so I can have the CO2 outside.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't** drill or use screws. Use magnets to hold drip trays etc.

**Chest freezers have refrigerant coils in the walls.**

Lids & doors are ok. Only risk hitting some electrical for the lights, but usually easy to trace and avoid.

Probe wires are usually fine just cutting the lid seal a little so they have a channel. Mine seal just fine without any modification to the cooler.

If you need tubing ports, it's best to build a collar, like on a keezer.

Comment: So maybe I will drill the hole for the CO2 in the door.

Comment: @OliverHörold if you add some pictures and your exact model of refrigerator we can he more. Fridge doors are usually safe. Some fridge sidewalls are too. Best to get some service diagrams of your specific model to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it has any kind of drain hole to allow defrosting liquid to drain out. In that case, and assuming you can remove any plugs from your cables, you could route them through there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is a chest freezer, you can inspire yourself by looking how people build a keezer:  [HOW TO BUILD A KEEZER by Northern Brewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHWy_Vlw3J4)

So you could add a wood rim between the chest and the lid, so that way, you can drill the wood without damaging the freezer.